# How do I allow rails to have javascript: in the data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I have a database of ad html, and some of them contain Javascript functions. Is there a way to have rails allow javascript: tags for a particular attribute on a particular model?

To clarify further, I can bring the html up in an edit form, but when I try to submit, my browser (Firefox) says the connection is reset.  IE gives me an error as well.  The only thing that allows the html to be submitted is to remove the javascript: from the  tag.

My guess is that this is a security measure by Rails to not allow javascript injection, however, I have no control over the html of these ads, and many have javascript in them.

If my guess is indeed correct, is there a way to override the security for this one attribute of this one model?  Or am I way off target here?

I am using Rails 2.3.4 on Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Now I've never used rails but the idea should be the same, you just want to store the javascript as a string, and then when you display it, do not escape the data. A better way to do this would be to link to your javascript and then just store calls to the functions in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I'm guessing you are using `sanitize`. Instead of sanitizing, consider transmitting and storing your javascript escaped, then unescape it when you actually need to use it.